# Rewriting dynamic url's using apache rewrite

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have a anchor tag in my html content like this `class="list-content" href="/abcd/test.html"`.
and this is in a lot of places in my html for a list of some results.
I need to append all these URLs that are in "href" by appending a prefix.

For example: `/abcd/test.html` should be dynamically changed as `newprefix/abcd/test.html`

If i have another one like `/xyz/some.html` then this should be changed as `newprefix/xyz/some.html`

I have explored different solutions over the internet and I have not found something that would fit my problem.

Comment: “I have a div element in…” - how are you converting the div into a clickable anchor/link? How do you differentiate requests that need to be rewritten? Eg. `/<something>/<file>.html`? Presumably you are wanting to keep the “newprefix” entirely hidden? Or not?

Comment: it is clickable in an anchor tag.i don't want to have the "newprefix" hidden. but i want to append it dynamically for all the url's that are part of the similar class(list-content)

Comment: This doesn't sound like a job for "apache / mod-rewrite / url-rewriting"? Using Apache you are only targeting the incoming request (and to expose "newprefix" it would need to be an external redirect, which would not be good for SEO, if that is a concern) - it does not actually change the link in your HTML source (that users can see), if that is what you are trying to do? What "different solutions" have you explored?

Comment: Hi @MrWhite i am not looking at changed the html source by appending the prefix. basically when we click on the link it opens up in a new tab with the URI in "href". i still want it to open the URI in a new tab with a prefix added(technically its a redirect to a different url but would be entirely similar but similar to jus adding a prefix at the beginning of that URI.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To implement an external redirect to prepend `/newprefix` to these requests you could do something like the following near the top of the root `.htaccess` (or server config).

For example:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^[^/]+/[^./]+\.html$ /newprefix/$0 [R=302,L]
```

The above will redirect requests for `/abcd/test.html` or `/xyz/some.html` to `/newprefix/abcd/test.html` and `/newprefix/xyz/some.html` respectively. Anything that matches the pattern `/<something>/<file>.html`.

`$0` is a backreference that contains the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

Note that this is not "url-rewriting" since you stated in comments that you do not want to "hide" the `/newprefix` part of the URL from your users. An external redirect is therefore the only solution if you are intending to use Apache / mod_rewrite (as tagged).

*Aside:* This is not particularly good for SEO, your users or your server since the user is externally redirected everytime they click one of your links, potentially doubling the number of requests that hit your server and slowing your users.